# Decimal of price and qty magento2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, price, qty

I have a problem in my customer panel myorder tab.
In my order i see price 12,125.0000 and QTY: 5.0000
how should i remove decimal from them? it is just in my order and methods that i used is like below:

```
$block->escapeHtml($_item->getRowTotalInclTax())
$_order->getShippingAmount();
$block->escapeHtml($_item->getQtyOrdered())
```

All of them has 4 decimal like this 0.0000
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove All Decimals :-**

```
$rowTotal = (int)$_item->getRowTotalInclTax(); //12,125
$qtyOrdered = (int)$_item->getQtyOrdered(); //5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **number_format** function of PHP to achieve this.

Below is the basic syntax of **number_format** function:

```
number_format(number,decimals,decimalpoint,separator)
```

- **number:** Required. The number to be formatted. If no other parameters are set, the number will be formatted without decimals and with comma (,) as the thousands separator.
- **decimals:** Optional. Specifies how many decimals. If this parameter is set, the number will be formatted with a dot (.) as decimal point
- **decimalpoint:** Optional. Specifies what string to use for decimal point
- **separator:** Optional. Specifies what string to use for thousands separator. Only the first character of separator is used. For example, "xxx" will give the same output as "x"

For example: If you write

```
<?php
echo number_format("1000000", 2, ".", "");
?>
```

It will output like 1000000.00